# Why can't my script access classes that are in different directory?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to access classes DealState and NotAnEndState that are in another directory, where I have a lib called move-to-go.

move-to-go folder contains modules where the one in my example is named deal_state.rb. When i open deal_state.rb it contains the following the code below.

Path to lib: F:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\move-to-go-5.3.0\lib\move-to-go

```
module MoveToGo
    module DealState
        # This is the default, a deal with a status with this state is
        # currently being worked on.
        NotAnEndState = 0

        # The deal has reached a positive end state, eg we have won
        # the deal.
        PositiveEndState = 1

        # The deal has reached a negative end state, eg we have lost
        # the deal.
        NegativeEndState = -1
    end
end
```

Path to my code: C:Users/Shahin/MigrationFolder/converter.rb

```
class Converter
    def configure(rootmodel)


         rootmodel.settings.with_organization do |organization|
             organization.set_custom_field( { :integration_id => 'source', :title => 'Källa', :type => :Link } )
         end

         rootmodel.settings.with_person  do |person|
             person.set_custom_field( { :integration_id => 'source', :title => 'Källa', :type => :String} )
         end

         rootmodel.settings.with_deal do |deal|
         assessment is default  DealState::NotAnEndState 
             deal.add_status( {:label => '1. Kvalificering' })
             deal.add_status( {:label => '2. Deal closed', :assessment => MoveToGo::DealState::PositiveEndState })
             deal.add_status( {:label => '4. Deal lost', :assessment => MoveToGo::DealState::NegativeEndState })
         end
    end
```

When I execute my script I get this error message:
C:Users/MyUserName/MigrationFolder/converter.rb:63:in `block in configure': uninitialized constant Converter::DealState (NameError)
Did you mean?  DEAL_SHEET

New things have however come to light. The error message seems to have an issue with the Converter-class, but i cant really interpret what it is implying.

Comment: This is hard to tell without knowing about your actually file/folder structure. Can you please elaborate on how the files are named, how are the classes/modules are named in the files and how do you require the files and use the constants?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have updated my issue, but as for your last question I believe I need to read up more on constants and how to require.

Comment: You did load that gem, yes? Show us how.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the error : `assessment is default DealState::NotAnEndState`.
First you should use `MoveToGo::DealState::NotAnEndState` and second `assessment is default` should be in a spec file not here.

If you juste remove this line, there should be no error anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I couldnt get it to work. New things have however come to light. The error message seems to have an issue with the Converter-class, but i cant really interpret what.

Comment: You are using this gem ? https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go
I think this line is the error `assessment is default  DealState::NotAnEndState`.
First you should use `MoveToGo::DealState::NotAnEndState` and second `assessment is default` should be in a `spec` not in this file.

Comment: If you juste remove this line, there should be no error anymore.So what's the purpose of this line ?

Comment: Thank you very much! I did exactly that and the error disappeared. I think the purpose of that line was to show that NotAnEndState is default. It wasn't me who wrote that line of code.

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I edited my answer (for other people to see what's the correct answer), is it ok?